# How do I keep multiple header rows visable when I use filters?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2016, headers

I have a Microsoft 365 Excel table with 4 header rows. When I add filters, all of the header rows disappear. How do I keep them visible?

Answer (score 0):

Select the data starting on the bottom-most header.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In my tests, the header rows doesn't disappear no matter how I use filtering.

If this does not apply to your situation, lock these 4 header rows.

Select these rows, right-click, select the cell format and select Lock in Protect.